# Replace array keys using an array of values

Tags: php, arrays

I'm currently working with a CSV file that I am converting into an array. However, I would like for my array keys to be the values of the first row. I'm looking for an easy way to get this done.

```
$newArray = [];
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$firstRow = fgetcsv($handle, 5000, ",");
while (false !== ($row = fgetcsv($handle, 5000, ','))) {
    $newArray[] = $row;
}
```

Now, `$row` will have numeric array keys as is usual with arrays. However, I would like `$firstRow` to replace those keys. Can someone help me out?

#### Update

As requested, some example data.

```
"name","age","active","date_added"
"John Doe","24","yes","2018-01-02"
"Jane Doe","41","yes","2018-01-03"
"Joe Doe","28","yes","2018-01-04"
"Janett Doe","30","no","2018-01-05"
```

Currently, `var_dump($row)` will output:

```
array(4) {
    [0]=> "John Doe"
    [1]=> "24"
    [2]=> "yes"
    [3]=> "2018-01-02"
}
```

The expected result:

```
array(4) {
    ['name']=> "John Doe"
    ['age']=> "24"
    ['active']=> "yes"
    ['date_added']=> "2018-01-02"
}
```

Comment: Add some example data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply with **`array_combine()`** function:

```
...
$newArray[] = array_combine($firstRow, $row);
...
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Comment: Much better (I completely forgot about `array_combine()`), +1.

Comment: Indeed, this seems like what I'm looking for. I'll give it a try.